$ L^p ( X ) \cap L^{\infty}( X) $ is a Banach space with respect only to the $p$-norm $\| \cdot \|_p$, $p<\infty$?
The space $^() \cap ^\infty()$, $p<\infty$,  with the norm $||||_{^ \cap ^\infty}=||||_+||||_\infty$ is a Banach space. I imagine that if we remove the norm $||||_\infty$ and leave only the $||||_$, the space $^() \cap ^\infty()$ with norm $||||_{^ \cap ^\infty}=||||_$  is not Banach, but how can we show this, what is the counterexample? Or is he Banach? Here I am not assuming that $X$ has finite measure.

Clearly $L^p(X) \cap L^\infty(X)$ is a subspace of $L^p(X)$ with the norm $|-|_p$. Do you know the criterion for when a subspace of a Banach space $X$ is itself a Banach space in the (restriction of the) norm of $X$?

@WhileIAm no, the criterion I know is that a subspace of a space is Banach if and only if it is closed.

That's the criterion I was thinking of. You can see by @Steen82 's argument that the subspace is not closed in the $p$-norm.

In general a  subspace $Y$ of a Banach space $X$ is complete iif $Y$ is closed. In particular if $Y$ is complete and dense then $Y=X.$

Let $f\geq0$ be an unbounded $L^p$ function. Let $f_n(x)=\min\{f(x),n\}.$ Then $f_n$ is in $L^{\infty}$ and $f_n\to f$ in with respect to the $p-$ norm.

Since $f$ is in $L^p$ and $f_n \leq f$ it follows that $f_n$in $L^p.$

@Ilovemath This is a valid answer. $(f_n)$ is Cauchy but not convergent in your space.

Got it, I agree. Interestingly, if you limit the function norm this becomes Banach https://math-stackexchange-com.translate.goog/questions/1672875/showing-that-the-following-set-is-closed-in-lp?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR&_x_tr_pto=sc
